# Execute an action without opening application in Android

Tags: android, icons, click, action

I have an application in Android that has a button in the MAIN activity that performs an action.

Is there a way to execute that action without opening the application?

I don't know if I can say it is like a widget, because it does not wait for updates.

The user should be able to execute that action just clicking on the icon of the application without opening.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. What I had to do for a similar problem was have a transparent view in my main activity, and then self-terminate:

In your activity...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Do whatever you need here...
    finish();
}
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <activity android:name=".whatever" android:theme="@android:
style/Theme.NoDisplay">
```

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: [`Theme.NoDisplay`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_NoDisplay) is more appropriate.

Comment: Hi folks! The Theme.NoDisplay works like a charm! I've tried to use Service too, and that works, but I think yours solution is much better!! Thanks a lot! Sorry for late feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this question [Android - How to execute main functionality of project only by clicking on the icon of application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567312/android-how-to-execute-main-functionality-of-project-only-by-clicking-on-the-ic)